# How to scrape "vague" information off a website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a "API" for a website which I don't own, and trying to scrape information off pages, however I've tried suggestions on stackoverflow and other locations about DOM and regex, which usually require a context or specific div id tags, which appears this site doesn't use and just uses generic ones, is there a way I can scrape information off the website?

HTML Example of something I would try to scrape:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <strong style="font-weight:500;">Date Created</strong>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  03-12-2016 4:08PM
div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 text-center">
  <font style="font-size:22px;">
    Feb 12, 2016
  </font>
   <br />
<div style="color:#999;">join date</div>
</div>
```

How would I be able to scrape the Date Created (the actual date) and the Join date? I'm not that advanced in web programming so I couldn't find anything else, I generally just use PHP.

Comment: If you know python, there is an awesome scrapping library, [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), that does this exact thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample is poor, so this is only an example to show the way.

Basing on this HTML sample:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <strong style="font-weight:500;">Date Created</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            03-12-2016 4:08PM
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 text-center">
            <font style="font-size:22px;">
            Feb 12, 2016
            </font>
            <br />
            <div style="color:#999;">join date</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

we use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors( 1 );
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
```

then we search for the correct path of join date:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 text-center"]/div[.="join date"]/preceding-sibling::font' );
```

and we output its node value:

```
echo trim( $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue );
```

Result:

> Feb 12, 2016

XPath is a language for addressing parts of an XML/HTML document using a short syntax for complex searches.

The above path means:

```
//                                           Following pattern no matter where they are in the document
div[@class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 text-center"]  <div> with class "col-xs-6 col-md-2 text-center"
/div[.="join date"]                          <div> with “join date” as node value
/preceding-sibling::font                     preceding sibling with tag <font>
```

So, you have to search in your HTML the best unique pattern to isolate desired node and write a appropriate pattern to match it.

---

- See more about [DOMDocument()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- See more about [DOMXPath()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- [xPath on W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [xPath on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [xPath on wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

Comment: I recieved this error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /www/public_api/store/getItemInfo.php on line 21"

Comment: I don't know what's in your file line 21: let me know. BTW, you have to pass to `->loadHTML()` the HTML content, not the file path (maybe this is the problem?) In my answer you have a lot of link to see commands syntax, more examples and tutorials.

Comment: Line 21 is trim( $created->item(0)->nodeValue which attempts to get info from $created = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="col-md-6"]/div[.="Date Created"]/preceding-sibling::div' );

Comment: So your path doesn't match: you don't have to copy-and-paste, you need to adapt-it to your document structure. in your example, i.e., div[.="Date Created"] has not preceding-sibling. See here for [xpath axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp)

Comment: I'm not all savvy on what each one stands for, I assume it would be the child axe?

Comment: So you have to read about it. You can't parse HTML without knowing HTML structure. in `<a><b></b><c></c><d></d></a>`,  `<b>` is child of `<a>`; `<a>` is parent of `<b>`, `<c>` and `<d>`; `<b>` is preceding sibling of `<c>`; `<d>` is following sibling of `<c>`

Comment: I'm probably messing it up.. but from what I can see the parent would be the col-md-6 for $xpath->query( '//div[@class="col-md-6"]/div[.="Date Created"]/parent::div[@class="col-md-6"]' ); however I get the error still, heck I even tried all the axes and still got the same error..

Sorry for being annoying with all the questions.

Comment: Try this one: `//div[@class="col-md-6"]/div[.="Date Created"]/following-sibling::div`

Comment: It worked.. sorta, I got "created" but I was trying to get the actual date of creation :/

Comment: The correct pattern is `//div[@class="col-md-6"]/strong[.="Date Created"]/../following-sibling::div` (tested as working) The problem is that in my example HTML is broken: `<div>` after `4:08PM` must be `</div>` (answer now is corrected). If your HTML is broken so, the pattern doesn't work in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If there no discernible consistent format of the data you want to scrape, it's not going to be easy. You'll need some sort of cleverness to find dates, and maybe the text "join date" within n characters distance from the date text (so you can assume it's related therefore you have their join date).

Not easy to make a reliable tool.